# ionic v3 social sharing plugin not woking android API 30

Tags: android, ionic-framework

After build for Android API 30, in Android 11, share not working anymore

```
share() {
    this.socialSharing.canShareVia('WhatsApp', "message", "subtitle", "https:example.com/image.png", "https:example.com/image.png")
    .then(() => { console.log("Can share via WhatsApp"); })
    .catch((error) => { console.log("Can't share via WhatsApp", error); });
  }
```

```
  error: com.android.bluetooh, com.android.google.gms, com.android.bips, etc
```

Comment: Hello Gladisson, can you add more information about the error? please paste the entire error here

Answer (score 1):

The query all packages permission is not given to all apps. Your app may get rejected by the play store if it doesn't justify permission use.

you can add [`<queries>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) to detect specific apps which accept the intent of sharing your content type.

The below example in config.xml is for requesting packages which accept plain text or images.

```
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</config-file>
```

If it is sharing with only a specific app, you can add a query with its [package name](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring).

```
 <config-file parent="/manifest" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    </queries>
</config-file>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution add this below on config.xml in android platform

```
<platform name="android">
     <config-file parent="/manifest" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
     </config-file>
    </platform>
```